# calculate SLA remaining days / time

Tags: javascript, reactjs, datetime

I need help trying to work out how to display SLA's based on some rules.
My API comes back with integer values for minutes, for example -1491 and 5836. My logic is incorrect. Can someone help me please.

The rules are as follows:

1. If SLA minutes is >= 24 hrs show days like e.g. "3 days"
2. If SLA minutes is less than 24 hrs show hours and minutes e.g. "3hrs 4mins"
3. If SLA minutes is less than 1 hr show minutes "33 mins"
4. If SLA minutes is -1441 it should return 1 day overdue and if the minutes was a postive number 1441 it should return 1 day

What I have so far is:

```
const items = [{slaMinutesRemaining: 5836}, {slaMinutesRemaining : -1441}]
```

I loop through items and pass item as prop:

```
const SLA = ({item}) => {

    const returnDays = (mins) => {
      const calc = Math.floor(mins / 1440);
      return calc > 1 ? `${calc} days` : `${calc} day`;
    };
    
    const returnHoursAndMinutes = (mins) => {
      const hrs = Math.floor(mins / 60);
      const minutes = mins % 60;
      if (mins < 1440) return `${hrs}hrs ${minutes} mins`;
      return mins;
    };
    
    const slaRemaining = (mins) => {
      console.log('minssss', mins);
      const hrs = Math.floor(mins / 60);
      // if null
      if (!mins) return 'N/A';
      let m = mins;
      const isNegative = m < 0;
      if (isNegative) m = Math.abs(isNegative);
      if (m >= 1440) return returnDays(m);
      if (hrs < 1) return m;
      return returnHoursAndMinutes(m);
    };

        return (
          <>
            {item.slaMinutesRemaining && item.slaMinutesRemaining < 0 ? (
              <SlaAlert>
                {slaRemaining(item.slaMinutesRemaining)}{' '}
                <OverDueTag>Overdue</OverDueTag>
              </SlaAlert>
            ) : (
              <>{slaRemaining(item.slaMinutesRemaining)}</>
            )}
          </>
        );
    }
```

Comment: Is the React code part of your issue? Not sure what `item` is, etc.

Comment: item is a prop which contains properties such as slaMinutesRemaining etc.

Comment: Im trying to solve the rules I posted.

Comment: This seem to do the trick

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First off, I would remove all that computation from the component itself so that it can be unit tested. That way, you would already know if the computation is correct.

```
if (isNegative) m = Math.abs(isNegative);
```

should probably be:

```
if (isNegative) m = Math.abs(m);
```

And you can simplify all your logic too:

```
const slaRemaining = (mins) => {
  if (!mins) {
    // This check is wrong. What happens if the query happens at the exact moment that 0 minutes are left to SLA?
    return 'N/A';
  }

  const due = (mins < 0);
  const absMins = Math.abs(mins);
  const days = Math.floor(absMins / 1400);
  const hours = Math.floor(absMins / 60);
  const minutes = absMins % 60;

  const label = days
    ? `${days} day${days > 1 ? 's' : ''}`
    : `${hours}hr${hours > 1 ? 's' : ''} ${minutes}min${minutes > 1 ? 's' : ''}`;

  return { due, label };
};
```

Comment: `const isNegative = m < 0;` isNegative will be a boolean (explaining your answer)

Comment: Thanks to add the explanation @ISAE, but I think here it was just an inattention, more than the fact that OP made a wrong use of `Math.abs()`.